# How to increase the writing speed of the streamwriter?

Tags: c#, winforms, web-applications

How to raise the speed of the streamwriter to write a 83MB csv file.
I have inceresed the buffersize to 65536 but its also consuming more time. How to improve the speed.

---

```
StreamWriter writer =new streamWriter(
      new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew), Encoding.UTF8, 65536))
string str=string.Empty;
while((str = reader.ReadLine())!=null)
    writer.WriteLine(str)}        
writer.Close()
```

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to write now?

Comment: How long is it taking, and how certain are you that it's the StreamWriter rather than just the time taken to work out the data you're writing?

Comment: Try out how long it takes to copy/paste the 512 MB csv file.. that's as fast as you can possibly make it.

Comment: For examble. 83mb file takes 34 mins 27 secs with buffersize 65536. If i didnt give the buffersize then it takes 35 mins and 50 secs

Comment: `StreamWriter writer =new streamWriter(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew), Encoding.UTF8, 65536))string str=string.Empty;While((str = reader.ReadLine())!=null)writer.WriteLine(str)}writer.close()`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the number of lines your CSV file contains, you could possibly end up with a loop that executes millions of times. Not a good idea to access the disk that many times.

The easy way out (if you have memory) is to read the entire CSV file in a string[] in memory (using File.ReadAll() i think), do your processing and write it all once (File.WriteAll() i think).
This will greatly increase your performance.

The other way out is to use asynchronous read/writes, increase buffer size AND create a mechanism to read bigger chunks of data. Having a big buffer if you are only reading 1 line will not help you.

Comment: ya.. but if i need to manipulate each lines of the file with some string manipulation. So how can i do that. and also what is the Maximum size of the buffer. If i set the size to the maximum then what will happen? Is that causes performance degration?

Answer (score 0):

I would try raising the buffer even more. At that buffer size it's going to take over 8200 writes to create the whole file. Try a buffer around 256K or 512K.

Comment: what is the maximum size for the streamwriter buffer? and If i increased the Buffersize to the maximum means will it degrade the performance?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment showing what your code is actualy doing:

```
File.WriteAllText( filePath, reader.ReadToEnd() );
```

Comment: I have to read a file of 83Mb and Write line by line into another file of same size. so i am using streamwriter to do that. but if the size of the file increases it consumes more time.